# MS ACCESS Query with sub queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I need your help to create two queries for MS Access Database that I can run from VB6. Here is my Table Schema of the tables (**ORDER, AMC, Customer**)

**Table 1: Order**
Order_ID
Order_Date
Customer_ID

**Table 2: AMC**
AMC_ID
Order_ID
Next_Renew_ID

**Table 3: Customer**
Customer_ID
Customer_Name

Now I want to do 2 selection from Order table That Does the following

**Query 1**
**Part 1:**  Select all those `Order_ID` from `AMC` where `Next_Renew_ID='N/A'`
**Part 2:**  Now Select all those records from `Order` where the `Order_ID` is not in the result of Part 1 of this Query.

**Query 2**
**Part 1:**  Select all those `Order_ID` from `AMC` where `Next_Renew_ID='N/A'`.
**Part 2:**  Now Select all those `Customer_ID`from `Customer` where the `Customer_Name Like 'Krish%'`.
**Part 3:**  Now Select all those records from `Order` where the `Order_ID` is not in the result of Part 1 of this Query and `Customer_ID` is in the result of Part 2 of this Query.

I know that It can be easily done using joining or something like that, but I'm really no good at sql. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 -- this uses the `LEFT JOIN` / `NULL` check.  This can also be achieved using `NOT IN` (or possibly `NOT EXISTS` assuming Access supports it):

```
SELECT O.*
FROM Order O
   LEFT JOIN AMC A ON O.Order_ID = A.Order_Id
      AND A.Next_Renew_ID = 'N/A'
WHERE A.Order_Id IS NULL
```

Part 2 -- using the same query as above, but adding an `INNER JOIN` to the customer table to make sure the customer first exists in that table:

```
SELECT O.*
FROM Order O
   INNER JOIN Customer C ON O.Customer_ID = C.Customer_Id
   LEFT JOIN AMC A ON O.Order_ID = A.Order_Id
      AND A.Next_Renew_ID = 'N/A'
WHERE A.Order_Id IS NULL AND  
    C.Customer_Name Like 'Krish%'
```

Comment: When tried to use these queries, Got error saying `JOIN Expression Not Supported.`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

My English is very poor, do not know if there is no understand what you mean

Query 1
part 2
    select * from Order where Order_ID not in (select a.Order_ID from Order a left join AMC b on a.Order_ID=b.a.Order_ID where Next_Renew_ID='N/A')

Query 2
part 2

```
select Customer_ID from Customer where Customer_Name Like 'Krish%'
```

part 3

```
select * from Order where Order_ID not in (select Distinct Order_Id from AMC where Next_Renew_ID='N/A') and Customer_ID in (select Customer_ID from Customer where Customer_Name like 'Krish%')
```